# @RetryableTopic without @KafkaListener

Tags: spring-boot, spring-kafka

I would like to use the functionalities offered by the @RetryableTopic annotation but
I do not have any @KafkaListener annotation.

I use the method  createContainer(final String... topics) from ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Serializable> and setup a listener using
setupMessageListener from the obtained container.

Do you know if it is possible to use the RetryableTopic in case of dynamic container creation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The feature doesn't currently support creating retryable topics outside of the `@KafkaListener` scope.

Feel free to raise a feature request in the project's GitHub so this can be kept in mind for `Spring Kafka`'s next major version due later this year.

Thanks